Laravel: Store function doesnot save my file name to database but stores file to folder
I want to store file in public folder and save that's name to MySQL database, database does not create record for file_name column.
When I post file then file moves to folder but database does not create record of file name, please help.

This is my controller store function
   $request->validate([
    "title"=>"required",
    "description"=>"required|string",
    "file_name"=>"nullable"
   ]);
   if($request->has('file')){
    $file=$request->file('file');
    $extension=$file->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $fileName=time().'.'.$extension;
    $path='postFiles';
    $file->move($path,$fileName);
   }

   $post=Post::create([
    'title'=> $request->title,
    'description'=> $request->description,
    'file_name'=>$fileName,
    'user_id'=>auth()->user()->id
   ]);
   $post->save();



this is database record
id title   description   user_id  file_name   created_at           updated_at 

1  title:  34636sdfg...  2        NULL          2024-04-16 09:06:41  2024-04-16 09:06:41




can you show the Post.php Model file?

Yes, we need to see the Post model

Have you added file_name to $fillable in Post Model?

follow this step

run command
php artisan optimize:clear

try this way


$fileName = null;
if ($request->hasFile('file_name')) {
    // Handle the file upload
    $file = $request->file('file_name');
    $fileName = time().'.'. $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $file->move(public_path('file'), $fileName);
}


   $post=Post::create([
    'title'=> $request->title,
    'description'=> $request->description,
    'file_name'=>$fileName,
    'user_id'=>auth()->user()->id
   ]);


if ($request->hasFile('file_name'))

Don't just dump code as answer. Please add some explanation of how your code fixes the problem so others can learn

Also, this is not a solution for his problem. As he says, the file is moved to the folder, thus the posted file is not stored in "file_name", but in "file". His problem is most likely a fillable problem.
